Form with transparent element
In C# on Windows 11, I have a form with a solid background and a transparent PictureBox. The form loads and the PictureBox is actually transparent, but when I move the mouse over the transparent area the mouse handling gets sent to objects behind the form.
Since I want the form to handle mouse over events for transparent areas I added an override for WndProc which intercepts the NCHITTEST message and returns the HTCLIENT value of 1. I think this is correct based on Microsoft WM_NCHITTEST message Document.
With this updated WndProc I can see the messages from Form_MouseMove; but none from PictureBox_MouseMove. And objects visible through the transparent element behind the form are handling the mouse.
I suspect it is possible to intercept these the mouse control messages and force my form to handle them but I can't seem to figure out how.
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TransparentFormExample
{
    public class TransparentForm : Form
    {
        private PictureBox pictureBox;

        public TransparentForm()
        {
            // Set form properties
            this.TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
            this.Size = new Size(500, 800);
            this.TopMost = true;

            // Initialize and set PictureBox properties
            pictureBox = new PictureBox
            {
                BackColor = Color.LimeGreen,
                Size = new Size(200, 200),
                Location = new Point(150, 300) // Centered in the form
            };

            // Add PictureBox to the form
            this.Controls.Add(pictureBox);

            // Add event handlers
            this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Form_MouseMove);
            pictureBox.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(PictureBox_MouseMove);
        }

        // Override WndProc to handle WM_NCHITTEST message
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84;
            const int HTCLIENT = 0x1;

            if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST)
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)HTCLIENT;
                return;
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        private void Form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mouse over form");
        }

        private void PictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // extra spaces to make it easier to spot if it happens
            Console.WriteLine("             Mouse over PictureBox");
        }

        public void Start () 
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault( false );
            
            Application.Run( this ); 
        }
    }
}

I'm starting the form using the following PowerShell, since I do not have the ability to create a DLL, compile .cs, and am not allowed to run .exe files.
write-host "load main.cs"

add-type -path "TransparentForm.cs" -ReferencedAssemblies @(
    "System.Windows.Forms"
    "System.Drawing"
    "System.Drawing.Primitives"
    )
$ProgramInstance = [TransparentFormExample.TransparentForm]::New()
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::Run( $ProgramInstance )


Is this Windows Forms, WPF, MAUI or some other technology?

This is using System.Windows.Forms

For your needs, you set the PictureBox "BackColor" to "Color.Transparent". Setting it to a TransparencyKey color effectively makes it "disappear".

You can take advantage of an age-old bug in Win7+, use Color.Red for the transparency key and the pb backcolor.

When setting the PictureBox.BackColor to Color.Transparent it does make the PictureBox transparent but results seeing through the picturebox into form's background. The goal is to be able to see other windows through the transparent hole in the form but still retain control of the mouse with in the form.

Did you try using Red (instead of Lime) as Hans Passant suggested?

@Loathing, Yes. I tried Color.Red and it resulted in the same problem.

@RoYoMi I tried it on Win8 and the Red trick worked. Another idea is to screen scrape the desktop (excluding the form), and then paint the contents in the PictureBox. Or you might be able to embed a WPF control.

@RoYoMi Example for WPF, have a transparent floating window that stays behind the form to capture the mouse events.

Starting with at least Windows 11, transparent elements on a System.Windows.Forms do not receive mouse events. Even when you create a custom WndProc override method. This method does not get called while your mouse is over a transparent element.
This might be a new bug, or they changed which function gets called when testing a form element for transparency.
The bottomline it can't be done without exploiting UI bugs which may or may not exist in Windows 11. Such a solution will likely get broken at some point, and may have already happened since the Color.Red "trick" does not seem to work.
The only solution is to create a second form that uses a nearly zero value for Opacity which will, for all practical purposes, appear transparent but allows that form to receive mouse events which can then be relayed your to the form with transparent elements.
Personally I was hoping to avoid the kludge, but it seems like the only option.
